# Scaling training data in a weka classifier

Tags: java, machine-learning, scaling, weka

I'm using a weka classifier a on a training set, but i'd like to scale it before building the model. The problem is that i don't know how to do it. Here is the code which builds the classifier and performs the prediction. Files in "trainPath" and "predictPath" are in arff format.

```
void classify(String trainPath, String predictPath) {
    try {
        DataSource trainData = new DataSource(trainPath);
        Instances train = trainData.getDataSet();
        if(train.classIndex() == -1)
            train.setClassIndex(train.numAttributes() -1);

        DataSource predictData = new DataSource(predictPath);
        Instances predict = predictData.getDataSet();
        if(predict.classIndex() == -1)
            predict.setClassIndex(predict.numAttributes() -1);


        Classifier cls = new LibSVM();
        cls.buildClassifier(train);

        Instances labeled = new Instances(predict);
        for (int c=0; c<predict.numInstances(); c++) {
            double clsLabel = cls.classifyInstance(predict.instance(c));
            labeled.instance(c).setClassValue(clsLabel);
        }

        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("files/labeled.arff"));
        bw.write(labeled.toString());
        bw.newLine();
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

}
```

I know that in Libsvm exists the svm-scale function, but i don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Weka provides you with methods for data preprocessing, in partciular

- `weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Normalize`
- `weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Standardize`

Sample usage of normalizator, which scales data to `[0,1]` interval (by default):

```
Normalize norm = new Normalize();
norm.setInputFormat(train);
Instances processed_train = Filter.useFilter(train, norm);
```